# Let's grab a drink sometime

Tags: translation, imperatives

I need help with a very easy sentence that for some reason I just can't seem to get right. I hate when this happens.

I'll be visiting Osaka next week and I can't think of a natural sounding way to tell a friend "By the way, I'll be in Osaka next week for a few days so let's go grab a drink or something."

ところで、来週は数日間大阪へ行くことになったから、よかったら飲みでもに行こうか？

I know this would get the meaning across but I need to know what's the most normal/natural sounding way to say it. I've known this person for quite some time now so feel free to use conversational Japanese.

Answer (score 7):

I believe it would be more correct to say `飲みにでも[行かない]{LLLH}？`.

1. `にでも` sounds more natural/correct to me than `でもに` for reasons I can't explain.
2. Since the whole clause is new information to your friend, you need the "suggestiveness" of the `いかない・いきませんか` instead of the more "decisive" `行こう`.
3. `よかったら` sounds a little too stiff for a close friend.  I'd go with something like `ひまなら` or `時間あったら`.
4. I think the `数日間` is unnecessary.